# Как заполнить таблицу кликабельными картинками при нажатии на ссылку?

Tags: asp.net

Есть таблица, на странице Default.aspx. Мне нужно заполнить таблицу кликабельными изображениями при клике на ссылку, которая находится над таблицей. Возможно ли это, как это сделать?

Comment: Уточните, чем выводите таблицу GridView? Можно сделать скрытый столбец, а при клике его показывать.

Потратьте, пожалуйста, на формулировку вопроса немножечко времени, чтобы быстрее получить точный ответ.

Comment: я думаю не важно какая таблица, кликабельные картинки - просто средствами хтмл - указать им параметром ссылку, а если надо что бы отображались после клика - так же методы...

Comment: Если всё написано на чистом хтмл, тогда верно. Но в случае asp.net это имеет значение, т.к. там разметка таблицы формируется полностью на сервере.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1) при нажатии на ссылку идет запрос на сервер и при помощи, например, c# кода формируется новый gridview, заполненный картинками.

2) при нажатии на ссылку отрабатывает js скрипт, который отображает в таблице, например, заранее погружение картинки либо заранее созданную, но скрытую таблицу.